# Use a class inside another class?

Tags: c#, class, using

I have a class in my program that I always have to access like this:

```
Blah.Blah.Blah.DoSomething();
```

And I want to be able to access DoSomething() without having to type all this out each time. `using Blah;` wouldn't compile, and wouldn't come up on Visual Studio's intellisense anyway. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Try `using MyBlah = Blah.Blah.Blah;`. Or, you know, don't overuse nested classes - that's what namespaces are for.

Comment: One way of avoiding this, is to not use nested classes..

Comment: Sigh, all these "it didn't work" questions makes for blah blah browsing.

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry, I'll rephrase it

Comment: Is `Blah.Blah` a namespace or static class? Please show a complete short example of what you currently have to do and what you want to do (even if what you wanted to do would not compile), see http://sscce.org/ for good guidelines on asking questions about code.

Answer (score 6):

Try this;

```
 using blah = blah.blah.blah;
```

Comment: Note that this will only work if `Blah.Blah.Blah` is a class, if it is a static property or field [it will not work](http://ideone.com/pp3lrH).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `using` directives only for Namespaces. You can think of namespaces like folders to organize classes. For instance, the `Console` class lives in the `System` namespace. So you can either access it with `System.Console` or with `using System; ... Console`.

You can use `using` directives only for namespaces, not for classes. In your example, the `DoSomething` is a method of the `Blah` class. Writing only `DoSomething` doesn't work, because the compiler wouldn't know which function you are looking for. Also sometimes large chains like in your example come up when you access properties of properties. Imagine, I have a `Color` class with a R, a G and a B value. Now I have a Pixel Class, that also stores an object of the Type `Color`. So to get the `R` value of such a Pixel, I could use `Pixel.Color.R`. In this case it's not possible to use `using`s, because neither Pixel nor Color is a namespace.

Edit: As Scott points out, you can indeed use using statement on classes. See below.

Comment: [Are you sure about using `using` only on namespaces](http://ideone.com/ZVvuwM)? You can use them on classes just fine, you just have to treat them like any other `Type`. Also for your pixel example you can do `Pixel pixel = new Pixel(); Color pixelColor = pixel.Color; int r = pixelColor.R;` just fine.

Comment: Of course you can extract the color from the Pixel and store it separately. But I was trying to find an example with many dots ;) For the `using` on classes, I didn't know that, thanks for the heads up. But still, you can't for instance write `using Int32;` and then simply call `ToString();` in code. The `using X = Y` creates something like an "alias", whereas the `using NAMESPACE` removes the need to write out the namespace altogether, that's what I was aiming at.

Comment: Yes, I agree, you will need at least one dot. The best you can do is to turn it in to `Alias.StaticFunctionName()`.